# How to get all columns in SQL after using DISTINCT and UNION functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, union, distinct

I am trying to write a Query that will combine historical appointment data with live-updating appointment data.

The Live Updating Data and Historical Data have all common column headers and data types.

The Historical Data set is a static snapshot of 100k-150k rows of data which I am trying to UNION with the Live-Updating Data to create a Full Data Set

Since there is some overlap between the Live-Updating Data and the Historical Data, I want to filter out Distinct appointment ID's

---

Here is the query that I've written:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT(n.appointment_id)
FROM (
  SELECT 
  * FROM note_data
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM note_data_historical) as n

FULL OUTER JOIN note_data_historical as historical
    on historical.appointment_id = n.appointment_id
  
FULL OUTER JOIN note_data as live
    on live.appointment_id = n.appointment_id
```

What I am trying to do is to avoid having to write out the couple of dozen column headers, but also not have duplicate rows.

---

So to summarize, I would like to:

1. Join Two Data Sets with Overlapping Rows to Get a Complete Data Set
2. Filter out Overlapping Rows
3. Get all of the columns to appear (like a SELECT * grouped by or joined on one column)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: So is the idea that you want note_data.* unioned with note_data_historical.* unless note_data_historical.appointment_id exists in note_data?

Comment: UNION guarantees uniqueness of each row in the result set. This is not the same as removing duplicates on any particular column or set of columns. If any column differs then the row is unique. If you need uniqueness on specific columns then, quit being lazy and specify the columns needed, or use union all and distinct on those specific columns by name. UNION ALL retains duplicate rows in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like the following

```
SELECT * 
FROM note_data
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM note_data_historical
WHERE note_data_historical.appointment_id NOT IN
(
 SELECT appointment_id FROM note_data
)
```

This gets all of your note_data and note_data_historical rows, unless the note_data_historical.appointment_id exists in note_data. And you don't need to list the columns in your query.

Note that I used a `UNION ALL` instead of a `UNION`, but since I don't know your data, I don't know if that's actually reasonable.

Comment: @Belayer This is not relying on the `UNION`/`UNION ALL` to remove the duplicates, it's using the `WHERE` clause for that. Based on my understanding of the question, OP considers duplicates the case where appointment_id exists in both tables. (It's possible I'm misunderstanding the question, of course.)

Comment: Sorry @EdmCoff, comment was intended for OP, guess I'll move it.  But it is an intersecting concept of getting history of a row where the id has changed.